# How can I test if all values in an associative array are true? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, logic

Associative array:

```
var signUpStates = {
    "CNPJ": false,
    "PASSWORDS": false,
    "ADDRESS": false,
    "GENERAL_FIELDS": false,
    "TERMS": false,
}
```

My attempt:

```
function updateButton() {
    var tempArray = []
    $.each(signUpStates, function(i, val) {
        tempArray.push(val);
    });
    if(tempArray.every(function(e, i, a) { return e == true; })) {
        $(".btn-cadastrar-fornecedor").attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(".btn-cadastrar-fornecedor").attr('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Iterating over it and checking individually does not work. What's the best approach to do such a test?

Comment: there should be a `.all()` function, depending on which lib you are using

Comment: In JavaScript, we just call them objects.

Comment: You should consider stating your array objects by setting its position like signUpStates = [], cnpj[0] = false, passwords[1] = false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straighforward solution (if you are asking about logic) would be to use for loop:

```
var is = true;

for (var key in signUpStates) {
    if (!signUpStates[key]) {
        is = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Strictly saying, correct approach would be also to check only own properties, this is important if the object you are testing might inherit properties from another objects:

```
var is = true;

for (var key in signUpStates) {
    if (signUpStates.hasOwnProperty(key) && !signUpStates[key]) {
        is = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

In simple cases like yours, this additional check is not needed.

Comment: *May* be worth a mention of `hasOwnProperty`. Not necessary given the OP's code, though. And +1, sometimes the old ways are best.

Comment: Yes, I thought about hasOwnProperty but in OP's case it's not necessary. But yes, better to mention.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of the object's property names from [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and then use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
if (Object.keys(signUpStates).every(function(name) { return signUpStates[name]; })) {
    // All are true
} else {
    // Not all are true
}
```

With ES2015's (aka ES6) arrow functions, this becomes a bit shorter:

```
if (Object.keys(signUpStates).every(name => signUpStates[name])) {
    // All are true
} else {
    // Not all are true
}
```

Support for ES2015 is still relatively thin on the ground, particularly if you have to handle browsers that were released before the spec was finalized, so if this is for a general web page, you'd not use them or use a transpiler. If this is for, say, NodeJS, you can use them directly in v4 and higher.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz: Far from it, I assume (but probably shouldn't) that people know that. I use transpilation.